# How to check for delimiter in netty tcp connection. And what's the use of delimiter

Tags: apache-camel, netty, netty-socketio

I have started to write tcp connection using netty component of Apache Camel. What is use of delimiter and how to know user are using delimiter when sending response back.

what's is the use of delimiter in tcp netty. As i am using spring-dsl for camel application. I am not able to confirm whether user sending delimiter in the end of response.